# Using shake API to detect shakes

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4, xcode4, motion-detection

The events like `motionBegan:` or `motionEnded:` used for monitoring shakes can be fired only when there is a first responder in my view. Okay, so I can make the view first responder like this: `[self.view becomeFirstResponder];`. But the view cannot be a first responder by default (why?) so I need to create a UIView subclass and override the default `canBecomeFirstResponder` to `YES`. How is this UIView subclass gonna help exactly? How does this all work? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide, especially the stuff about first responder:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1